# JMS Message Parse Exception

Tags: java, xml, parsing, jms, sax

My java code is taking XML messages from my local ActiveMQ queue. Now it can successfully consume messages from the queue, but it seems fails to parse it? My xml data looks like this:

```
 #---------- #1 :  ----------#
 <MSG_INFO>
    <message type="TextMessage" messageSelector="" originationTimestamp="" receiveTime="" jmsServerTimestamp="" jmsMsgExpiration="">
     <header JMSDestination="Asurion.SYD02.Q.Business.NonPersistent.Policy.PublishTelstraAMAEnrollments" JMSDestinationType="Queue" JMSDeliveryMode="1" />
        <properties>
        <property name="Client" type="String">Telstra</property>
       </properties>
    </message>
 </MSG_INFO>
 BodyLength=850
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <ns0:PublishEnrollmentRequest xmlns:ns0="http://services.asurion.com/schemas/PolicyAdministration/PublishEnrollmentRequest/1.0">
  <ns0:Parameters>
    <ns0:Enrollments>
        <ns0:MDN>9890667692</ns0:MDN>
        <ns0:FeatureCode>MBBPHPMPS</ns0:FeatureCode>
        <ns0:ProductName>MTS-SA</ns0:ProductName>
        <ns0:Status>Active</ns0:Status>
        <ns0:Active>Y</ns0:Active>
        <ns0:EffectiveDate>2013-07-02T19:36:51-04:00</ns0:EffectiveDate>
        <ns0:EnrollmentType>Customer</ns0:EnrollmentType>
        <ns0:Make>UnKnown</ns0:Make>
        <ns0:Model>UnKnown</ns0:Model>
        <ns0:ActivationDate>2013-07-02T19:36:51-04:00</ns0:ActivationDate>
        <ns0:ESN />
        <ns0:IMEI />
        <ns0:SubID>281474977839805</ns0:SubID>
        <ns0:Operation>Enrollment Added</ns0:Operation>
    </ns0:Enrollments>
</ns0:Parameters>
```

The exception I am getting now is:

```
  Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Unexpected element: CDATA
```

I understand it might be the BodyLength tne  that may cause this problem, but if I got rid of them, my code will not be able to extrat client information from it.

Is this something configurable in the code? Thanks.

Comment: Why is statement **BodyLength=850 hanging**. Put it inside some tag. and the statement **<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>** must at the starting of the xml. Encoding should not matter but that statement must be at the beginning of the xml. Otherwise your **xml is invalid**. No wonder parser will not parse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change your xml to the following if you can:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <ns0:PublishEnrollmentRequest xmlns:ns0="http://services.asurion.com/schemas/PolicyAdministration/PublishEnrollmentRequest/1.0">
  <ns0:Parameters>
    <ns0:Enrollments>
        <ns0:MDN>9890667692</ns0:MDN>
        <ns0:FeatureCode>MBBPHPMPS</ns0:FeatureCode>
        <ns0:ProductName>MTS-SA</ns0:ProductName>
        <ns0:Status>Active</ns0:Status>
        <ns0:Active>Y</ns0:Active>
        <ns0:EffectiveDate>2013-07-02T19:36:51-04:00</ns0:EffectiveDate>
        <ns0:EnrollmentType>Customer</ns0:EnrollmentType>
        <ns0:Make>UnKnown</ns0:Make>
        <ns0:Model>UnKnown</ns0:Model>
        <ns0:ActivationDate>2013-07-02T19:36:51-04:00</ns0:ActivationDate>
        <ns0:ESN />
        <ns0:IMEI />
        <ns0:SubID>281474977839805</ns0:SubID>
        <ns0:Operation>Enrollment Added</ns0:Operation>
    </ns0:Enrollments>
</ns0:Parameters>
 <MSG_INFO>
    <message type="TextMessage" messageSelector="" originationTimestamp="" receiveTime="" jmsServerTimestamp="" jmsMsgExpiration="">
     <header JMSDestination="Asurion.SYD02.Q.Business.NonPersistent.Policy.PublishTelstraAMAEnrollments" JMSDestinationType="Queue" JMSDeliveryMode="1" />
        <properties>
        <property name="Client" type="String">Telstra</property>
       </properties>
    </message>
 </MSG_INFO>
 <body  BodyLength="850" />
</ns0:PublishEnrollmentRequest>
```

If you don't want to change your xml try separating you xml above and beneath `BodyLength=850`. and use `<?xml version="1.0" encoding=utf-8"?>` in the beginning of the file

Comment: changed to your suggested xml, this time I got error:Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Unexpected element: OPEN_TAG

Answer (score 1):

Your data is not [well-formed XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_document) and cannot be parsed with an XML parser as-is. You'll have to find a way to separate the XML data before and after the `BodyLength=850` line and parse them separately.